# How to await inside RxJS subscribe method

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, rxjs

Inside of an RxJS subject's subscribe callback, I want to `await` on an `async` function. Below is a code example which the typescript transpiler complains about saying:

> Error:(131, 21) TS2304:Cannot find name 'await'.

```
async ngOnInit() {
  this.subscriber = dateSubscription.subscribe((date: Date) => {
    let dbKey = await this._someService.saveToDatabase(someObject);
    // wait for db write to finish before evaluating the next code
    // ... some other code here
  });
}
```

Usually I see this when trying to call await inside a non `async` function. Do I somehow need to make the subscribe callback `async` or am I going about this wrong? The function `saveToDatabase` is `async` and returns a promise resolving to the database primary key that was written to.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You do not need to use `await`, nor need to convert your `Promise` to an `Observable`.

---

CF this [Tweet](https://twitter.com/BenLesh/status/859551489487798272) from Ben Lesh :

[image]

---

Here's an example with a mock for the function `saveToDatabase` :
*(and the working Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/7SDLvRS2aTw9gYWdIznS?p=preview)*

```
const { Observable } = Rx;

const saveToDatabase = (date) =>
  new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() =>
      resolve(`${date} has been saved to the database`),
      1000));

const date$ = Observable.of(new Date()).delay(1000);

date$
  .do(x => console.log(`date received, trying to save it to database ...`))
  .switchMap(date => saveToDatabase(date))
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe();
```

Output :
[image]

Answer (score 25):

you can just directly add async signature to the anonymous function call in subscribe

```
 this.subscriber = dateSubscription.subscribe(async (date: Date) => {
    let dbKey = await this._someService.saveToDatabase(someObject);
    // wait for db write to finish before evaluating the next code
    // ... some other code here
  });
```

Comment: Why would that work? Does the observable implementation call `await` in `subscribe`? Didn't work for me, would love more info..

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can put an async function in there but it will not behave the way you'd expect. For example, when you do `Subject.next()` to notify observables, the call will not complete until all the subscriptions have executed. However, if you put an async subscription in there the call to `next()` will complete immediately, `Subject.next()` will *not wait* for the async subscriptions.

Comment: @MgSam is totally right, this is approach is elusive. Using `await` inside the subscriber function may introduce unexpected side effects, as the values emitted by the observable are not guaranteed to be processed gradually anymore.

Comment: @MgSam is right. Don't use `subscribe(async` - there's the option to use `switchMap` instead:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

 If you would like more than one inner subscription to be maintained, try `mergeMap`!
 `switchMap` is generally considered a safer default to `mergeMap`!
 `switchMap` can cancel in-flight network requests!

Answer (score 15):

**Update:**
Found easy for one time promises just use `toPromise` in front of the subscriber [(blog)](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html). So for the above case it will be like this:

```
const title = await this.translate.get('MYBOOK-PAGE.PAGE_TITLE').toPromise();
```

**Old way:**
Here's my method of solving this issue

```
const title = await new Promise<string>(resolve => 
  this.translate.get('MYBOOK-PAGE.PAGE_TITLE')
   .subscribe(translated => {
     resolve(translated)
   }));
```

Here what I'm doing is changing my Observable to a Promise

> Note: Here the only problem is this is one time show ie. if you
>   subscribe once you won't able to access it again. Suited me so sharing
>   here.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot `await` Observables directly, however you can `await` a `Promise`.

## Update

The `.toPromise()` method is being *deprecated* in RxJS 8, so you can use `lastValueFrom()` or `firstValueFrom()`.

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
this.categories = await lastValueFrom(categories$);
```

Thanks to [Robert Rendell's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881504/how-to-await-inside-rxjs-subscribe-method/43891875?noredirect=1#comment118830946_43891875).

## Prior to RxJS v8

You can simply use the `.toPromise()` method on the observables subscription. Consider the following:

```
async ngOnInit() {
  const date = await dateSubscription.toPromise();      
  let dbKey = await this._someService.saveToDatabase(someObject);
}
```

When you `await` the promise of the `dateSubscription` you'll be handed a `Date` object. Then you can continue with the next line of your execution, which makes reading your code more sequential.

Some people are thinking the angular will not wait for the `ngOnInit` to complete, it does not have a choice. Take a look at the resulting `JavaScript` from the given `TypeScript` [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20OnInit%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ngOnInit()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20stackoverflow%20implements%20OnInit%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20async%20ngOnInit()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20await%20null%3B%20%2F%2F%20for%20example%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D). As you can see, the `ngOnInit` will invoke the awaiter which internally manages and executes the underlying state-machine (generator). Angular doesn't have any control over that. It simply wants that method to invoke.

Comment: toPromise is being deprecated in RxJS 8, so you can use `lastValueFrom` or `firstValueFrom`. See usage here:
`import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';`
`this.categories = await lastValueFrom(categories$);`


When we want to use `firstValueFrom` we are not interested in the completion of the stream at all. What we want is its first emitted value, resolve the Promise with it and unsubscribe from the stream.
Taken from https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated

Answer (score 6):

Rxjs in 2022: use `pipe` and `concatMap`

I ended up here looking for the ability to await processing expensive items before listening to the next published item. I had to alter my code from `async` inside the `subscribe` handler to use a `pipe` and `concatMap` as per [this other similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64946990/3897838).

OLD code, does **not** wait for expensive call on item before handling new items (thus race conditions abound in my case):

```
myObservable$.subscribe(async (item) => { await expensiveFoo(item); })
```

NEW code, **does** await expensive function before processing next item.

```
let subscription = myObservable$.pipe(
    concatMap(async (item) => { await expensiveFoo(item); })
).subscribe(
    (item) => simpleFoo(item),// can also handle sync code here if you want 
    (error) => handleError(error), 
    () => handleComplete()
);
```

Be sure to keep around a reference to the `subscription` (it isn't the subscriber) until you're done with the observable.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a **TaskQueue** to make sure the asynchronous functions inside subscriptions can be executed one by one.

Go checkout the demo: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/task-queue-for-rxjs-g1prs6?file=/src/App.js:1523-1543)

```js
const ob$ = new Subject()
const subOb$ = new Subject()

async function asyncFunc() {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random(1) * 1000))
}

// Without [TaskQueue]
ob$.subscribe(x => {
  subOb$.next(x)
})
subOb$.current.pipe(switchMap(asyncFunc)).subscribe()  // <- My main goal is to make sure the [asyncFunc] is executed asyncronously.

// With [TaskQueue]
const taskQueue = new TaskQueue(subOb$)
ob$.subscribe(x => {
  taskQueue.next(x)
  // or
  taskQueue.nextAsync(x)
})
taskQueue.subscribe(asyncFunc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an updated response to this problem. I had a similar need to await responses, and rather than using `await` or setTimeout() method inside the Observable implementation, a cleaner way now is to use the RxJS built-in `interval()` method before completing the subscription.

Try this in the service:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
...

// inside your method
const source = interval(100);
    source.subscribe(x => {
        subject.next(CONNECTIONS_DATA);
        subject.complete();
});
return subject;
```

RxJS Docs:
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject#reference-counting

Hopefully a bit helpful if anyone is trying to do this more recently.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers seem to adequately answer OP's original question. Here is my simple solution to using `async`/`await` the observable callbacks using [IIFEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression).

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const someAsyncFunction = async (message: string) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(message);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

const myObservable = new Observable((subscriber) => {
  (async () => {
    const message1 = await someAsyncFunction('hello world');
    subscriber.next(message1);
    subscriber.next(message1);
  })()
    .then(
      () => subscriber.complete(),
      (err) => subscriber.error(err)
    )
});

myObservable.subscribe({
  next: async (message1) => {
      console.log(message1);
      const message2 = await someAsyncFunction('goodbye world');
      console.log(message2);
      console.log('done');
  },
  error: (err) => console.log(err),
  complete: () => console.log('complete')
});
```

Output:

```
hello world
hello world
complete
goodbye world
done
goodbye world
done
```

Note that the `complete` callback is called *before* the `next` callbacks finish executing. This is how the `rxjs` observable works when the `next` function includes asynchronous activities and can't be avoided. If you need `complete` to be called strictly after `next` finishes, you'll need to make your own Observable implementation or equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

`async ngOnInit() { }` is incorrect signature, because this is how Angular defines `OnInit` interface. It should returns `void`:

```
 export interface OnInit { ngOnInit(): void; }
```

If you have any promise to process after `dateSubscription` you can use `Observable.fromPromise` like

```
 dateSubscription
 .flatMap(x=>
      Observable.defer(Observable.fromObservable(this._someService.saveToDatabase(someObject)))
   ).subscribe()
```

Comment: `fromPromise` is unnecessary if you are using `flatMap` or `defer`.

Comment: You are incorrect, you can absolutely use `async` on the `ngOnInit`.

Comment: You have to implement an interface defined by Angular. You can put async but Angular won't do then on OnInit and won't wait.

Comment: Angular will wait, angular doesn't have a choice. The resulting `.js` wraps it the implementation of the interface with the awaiter that was generated. Look at [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20OnInit%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ngOnInit()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20stackoverflow%20implements%20OnInit%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20async%20ngOnInit()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20await%20null%3B%20%2F%2F%20for%20example%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D), note the right hand side.

Comment: it doesn't wait without then on result https://gist.github.com/ipassynk/f562c773c9e0051a7dbc2e2c37baf87b

Comment: `async ngOnInit() Promise<void>` is acceptable.