# How to chain Observable and Promise (Async/Await, RxJS, Observable)

Tags: typescript, promise, rxjs

I would like to know how can i do something like that in typescript with await/async and RxJS :

```
async function bar(): Promise<boolean>{ ... }

function boo(): Observable<any> { ... }

function baz(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable
         .fromPromise(() => bar())
         .map(() => boo())
}
```

To summary, i have multiple stream of baz which i will chain later with **zip**. In each baz(), i need to do some async check.
But nothing append... Observable.fromPromise is working as expected. Boo does not. It's like when i subscribe to the stream (**zip(baz1(), baz2())**), boo is never executed.

Am i missing something ? What is the best practice in this story ?

EDIT :

Here is the first part of code :

```
syncResource(urlEndpoint: string, storeCollectionKey: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable
        .fromPromise(this.shouldSyncResource(urlEndpoint, storeCollectionKey))
        .map((shouldUpdateResource) => {
            if(!shouldUpdateResource){ return Observable.empty(); }
            // here i can get "shouldUpdateResource" value

            return this._Remote.get(urlEndpoint, this._getRequestOptions())
                .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                .map((collection) => {
                    collection.forEach((item) => {
                        this._Stores[storeCollectionKey].update(item);
                    });
                });
        });
}
```

Here is the second part :

```
Observable.zip(
   syncResource('/poultries', 'poultriesStoreKey'),
   syncResource('/buildings', 'buildingsStoreKey')
).subscribe(() => console.log('Syncing done'))
```

Comment: You need to pass a Promise to `fromPromise`, not a function that returns a Promise, see http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise

Comment: Thx Martin, but even when i "force" with .fromPromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true)))
It doesn't work, and i can get the promise's value return in any cases

Comment: Do you subscribe to the Observable returned from `baz()`?

Comment: Yes, later in my code i'm using .zip(baz(), baz()).subscribe()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43885089/2398593

Answer (score 1):

Ok it is resolved. I needed to use **mergeMap** and **return a value** in the second part of code :

```
syncResource(urlEndpoint: string, storeCollectionKey: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable
        .fromPromise(this.shouldSyncResource(urlEndpoint, storeCollectionKey))
        .mergeMap((shouldUpdateResource, index) => {
            if(!shouldUpdateResource){ return Observable.empty(); }

            return this._Remote.get(urlEndpoint, this._getRequestOptions())
                .do((response: Response) => this.rememberResponseHashIfPresent(response.headers.get('x-hash'), storeCollectionKey))
                .map((response: Response) => {
                    console.log(response.json());
                    return response.json();
                })
                .map((collection) => {
                    collection.forEach((item) => this._Stores[storeCollectionKey].update(item));
                    return true;
                });
        });
}
```